# How to load only selected data from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have plist with Root as Array and then each item in this array is a Dictionary with objects: name(String) and surname(String). I want display all the names from my file. At the moment I am using this code:

```
   NSArray *myData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:mypath];
   NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int i=0; i < myData.count; i++) {
       [names addObject:[[myData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
   }
```

Is it any way that I could load values for the key @"name" straight from the plist file to NSMutableArray *names? I just don't want to load whole content of the plist file to memory if I only need @"name" values.

Comment: you cant if your plist is designed like this. how big is the plist? i really whould not be worried by that.

Comment: it is not big at the moment, but I will have Dictionaries with around 30 keys each and if I will want to display let say only "names" values in my UITableView than I have to load all data into memory (all keys and values). I am just afraid if my plist file will become very big I may have some memory issues later on.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about that too much.. If you really want to load something separately put it in a separate plist.

Comment: This has little to nothing to do with Xcode. Retagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Loading a plist is an all-or-nothing affair. Unless your plist is *massive* I wouldn't worry about it. And if it is, then you would want to consider splitting it up into multiple files rather than doing something like writing your own plist deserializer (because I guarantee you that CoreFoundation's plist parser is going to be faster than yours).